# .call alternative in kernel mode

Tags: debugging, windbg

I see that `.call` is not supported in kernel mode for WinDbg. But I seem to remember GDB does allow `call` with kernel mode debugging.

Can anyone:

- Suggest how I could call an arbitrary function in WinDbg in kernel mode debugging
- Explain why `.call` is only supported in user mode?

Comment: Why-questions are often hard to answer. This is often a decision of the product manager and only known to a limited number of people.

Answer (score 0):

Raymond Chen describes how `.call` is implemented here:
[Stupid debugger tricks: Calling functions and methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/27/2292037.aspx)

> Back in the old days, if you wanted to call a function from inside the debugger, you had to do it by hand: Save the registers, push the parameters onto the stack (or into registers if the function uses fastcall or thiscall) push the address of the ntdll!DbgBreakPoint function, move the instruction pointer to the start of the function you want to call, then hit "g" to resume execution. The function runs then returns to the ntdll!DbgBreakPoint, where the debugger regains control and you can look at the results. Then restore the registers (including the original instruction pointer) and resume debugging. (That paragraph was just a quick recap; I'm assuming you already knew that.)

You would need a different return address since ntdll!DbgBreakPoint is a user mode address. Since he mentions using `g` then you would want to set a breakpoint on the return address.